# Magento 2 - Dynamic rows based on related products modal grid on custom form with tabs

Tags: magento2, grid, modal, dynamic-rows

I am working on **magento 2.1** backend module. Basically backend part is a form that contain tabs. Here i have some standard inputs but also some dynamic rows etc. Everything is working fine except the last tab. Last tab is a MODAL that allow us to choose products that will not be available for the entity that we are editing/creating.

Basically idea of working is exactly same as on product edit form for related products, so: we have a button "**Add related products**", modal render with grid of products then we can select them and after click "**Add selected products**" we have them rendered in dynamic grid rows.

I was able to reproduce some part of this logic on my custom form:

- custom tab with button "Add unavailable products"
- after click modal render
- inside modal I have a product list
- when selecting product and clicking "Add selected products" modal disappear
- when opening modal again the list is filtered (does not contain previously selected elements)
- DYNAMIC GRID is not populated :(

I do not know where is the problem with dynamic grid. There are no errors in the console, no error logs, etc. Does anyone worked with those components or maybe have a idea what to do to make it works?

I saw some referrences into this doc:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui-components/ui_dynamic_rows.html
but it is not working.

This is how the tab looks like:
[image: Edit form tab with modal]

Some implementation details:

Main form is declared on `adminhtml/ui_component/my_component_form.xml` and looks like this:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">my_component_form.my_component_form_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">my_component_form.my_component_form_data_source</item>
        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">my_component_form</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Agency Information</item>
    <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        <item name="navContainerName" xsi:type="string">left</item>
    </item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="back" xsi:type="string">MyModule\Agency\Block\Adminhtml\Agency\Edit\BackButton</item>
        <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">MyModule\Agency\Block\Adminhtml\Agency\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
        <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">MyModule\Agency\Block\Adminhtml\Agency\Edit\ResetButton</item>
        <item name="save" xsi:type="string">MyModule\Agency\Block\Adminhtml\Agency\Edit\SaveButton</item>
        <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">MyModule\Agency\Block\Adminhtml\Agency\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
    </item>
    <item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="my_component_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">MyModule\Agency\Ui\Component\Edit\Form</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">my_component_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">agency_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">agency_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="my_component/agency/save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Last tab is added with Modifier class (like Related product), and my `adminhtml/di.xml` file looks like:

```
    <virtualType name="MyModule\Agency\Ui\Component\Edit\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="availability" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">MyModule\Agency\Ui\Component\Edit\Modifier\UnavailableProducts</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="MyModule\Agency\Ui\Component\Edit\Form">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pool" xsi:type="object">MyModule\Agency\Ui\Component\Edit\Modifier\Pool</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="MyModule\Agency\Ui\Component\Edit\Modifier\UnavailableProducts">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">my_component_form.areas</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

My getMeta method on `DataProvider class (Form)` is:

```
    public function getMeta()
{
    $meta = parent::getMeta();

    /** @var ModifierInterface $modifier */
    foreach ($this->pool->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
        $meta = $modifier->modifyMeta($meta);
    }

    return $meta;
}
```

And last part my `modifier class extends Related products class`, and field construction looks like:

```
 class UnavailableProducts extends Related
{
...
...
...
  /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getButtonSet(Phrase $content, Phrase $buttonTitle, $scope)
    {
        $config = parent::getButtonSet($content, $buttonTitle, $scope);
        $modalTarget = $this->scopeName . '.' . 'unavailable' . '.' . $scope . '.modal';

        // We need to update some button config in order to make sure that the modal box is linked to the proper button
        $config['children']['button_' . $scope]['arguments']['data']['config']['actions'][0]['targetName'] = $modalTarget;
        $config['children']['button_' . $scope]['arguments']['data']['config']['actions'][1]['targetName'] = $modalTarget . '.' . $scope . '_product_listing';

        return $config;
    }


    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                // Let's add a new fieldset group
                static::EASYCORE_AGENCY => [
                    'children' => [
                        'button_set' => $this->getButtonSet(
                            __('Products that are present here are not available for this agency'),
                            __('Add Unavailable Products'),
                            $this->scopePrefix . 'unavailable'
                        ),
                        'modal' => $this->getGenericModal(
                            __('Add Unavailable Products'),
                            $this->scopePrefix . 'unavailable'
                        ),
                        'unavailable' => $this->getGrid('unavailable')
                    ],
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Unavailable products'),
                                'collapsible' => false,
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => static::DATA_SCOPE,
                                'sortOrder' => 200
                            ],
                        ],

                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }
```

If we take a look inside Related class we will see that on `grid config` there is value like:

```
'links' => [
     'insertData' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataProvider }'
],
```

**I suspect that the problem is somewhere on grid or dynamic row configuration**... But I am unable to find it on my own :/ Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **dynamicRows dataScope & dataProvider is wrong**. I faced same problem. After changing dataScope & dataProvider grid is populated.

```
<dynamicRows name="orders">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.orders_tab.links</item>
        <item name="dataProvider" xsi:type="string">data.orders_tab.my_module_sales_order_listing</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<container name="record"/>
```

Before:

```
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.links</item>
```

After:

```
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.orders_tab.links</item>
```

**orders_tab** is name of tab where are **dynamicRows & insertListing placed.**